# React- Mock window.scrollTo similar to preventDefault() using Jest Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I have this simple test case where it checks if the `onSubmit` button is clicked and if `preventDefault()` is called.

This works well but I am having a problem testing `window.scrollTo()`. Can someone please help me in suggesting how do I mock `window.scrollTo` in a similar way

```
describe("should render label", () => {
let mockPreventDefault;
let mockEvent;

beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    onSubmit = jest.fn();
    validate = jest.fn();
    mockPreventDefault = jest.fn();
  });

it("should call preventDefault on onSubmit call", () => {
    instance.onSubmit(mockEvent());
    expect(mockPreventDefault).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

});
```

PS- I tried all the ways mentioned in StackOverflow. Tried global.scrollTo instead of `window.scrollTo`, I also tried using spyOn but none of these worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the unit test solution:

`index.jsx`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SomeComponent extends Component {
  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.scrollTo({ top: 0 });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}></form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SomeComponent;
```

`index.spec.jsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import SomeComponent from './';

describe('SomeComponent', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it('should handle submit correctly', async () => {
    window.scrollTo = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallow(<SomeComponent></SomeComponent>);
    const mEvent = { preventDefault: jest.fn() };
    wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit', mEvent);
    expect(mEvent.preventDefault).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(window.scrollTo).toBeCalledWith({ top: 0 });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59494359/index.spec.jsx (13.043s)
  SomeComponent
    ✓ should handle submit correctly (16ms)

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.jsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        15.192s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59494359

Comment: slideshowp2- i saw your similar post in one of the stackoverflow topics. but this doesnt work. i am still not able to call window.scrollTo.

Comment: @user3019647 What error you got? I guess it's an environment issue.